# Meaning of libcurl messages and execution process

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl

I am using `libcurl` library to fetch `abc-1.tar` file from server. I want to know meaning of message which is display and process of execution of `libcurl` to display this messages.

For Example: I provide some messages below out of that I know basic message meaning like `Content-Length` means length of file which are downloaded, etc.

I want meaning of all messages, particularly messages which are start with `*` (e. g. `Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact`)

```
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (nil)
* Connected to (nil) (182.72.67.14) port 65101 (#0)
GET /...... HTTP/1.1
Host: 182.72.67.14:65101
Accept: */*
Connection:keep-alive
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Length: 186368
< Content-Type: application/x-tar
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc-1.tar
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2013 06:29:00 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact
```

Answer (score 38):

[cURL's Man Page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) specifies three types of "special" verbose output:

> A line starting with '>' means "header data" sent by curl, '<' means "header data" received by curl that is hidden in normal cases, and a line starting with '*' means additional info provided by curl.

You can read about [HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) in the [HTTP official publication page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Any other output lines displayed by cURL belong to the HTTP body carried by the corresponding message.

So what is the actual meaning of these informationals starting with `*`, you ask? They inform you about the status of the transfer's TCP connection with the host. For instance:

- `"Connected to (nil) (182.72.67.14) port 65101 (#0)"` means that a TCP connection is established with the server side (in your case: 182.72.67.14). The `#0` is the TCP session number (which is used only by cURL). The `nil` indicates that the host name couldn't be resolved via DNS (had it been resolved, the it would've appeared instead of `nil`).
- `"Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact"` means that although the transfer is over, the TCP session itself is still open (*i.e* no FIN/ACK exchanges have been made), allowing you to keep reusing the same TCP connection for multiple transfers (which could be useful if you don't want to sacrifice time on opening a new TCP connection).

  The message `"Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (nil)"` supports that, indicating that cURL does indeed that, riding an existing TCP connection (from a previous transfer).

Comment: does `"Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact"` suggest `keep-alive`, is being set by the server?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu I would assume so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Marked by `<` are HTTP headers.You can read in detail about http headers and their meaning [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)
and marked by `*` are verbose information provided by `curl` which is displayed on `stderr`.

Comment: I want detail information of marked by '*'. Is there any path to know about this.